# Como hacer reconocer los td en segun categoria

Tags: javascript, php

Hola amigos un saludo cordial, como puedo hacer que reconozca los id en un echo que tengo de cada cronograma de un usuario, me pueden ayudar a solucionarlo, adjunto mi código:

```
<td>
<span class="categoria">
<?php 
 if ($dario['categoria']==1) {
       echo '<a href='a_conograma_2023_i.php?id=<?php echo $dario['id']'></a>';
                            
  } else if ($dario['categoria']==2){
        echo '<a href='a_conograma_2023_ii.php?id=<?php echo $dario['id']'></a>';
                        
  } else if ($dario['categoria']==3){
       echo '<a href='a_conograma_2023_iii.php?id=<?php echo $dario['id']'></a>';                       
} ?>
</span>
```

Comment: Buen día, el código debe estar en su respectivo formato, no en imágenes, por favor.

Comment: Tampoco se entiende la pregunta

Comment: Hola, ¿qué significa *como puedo hacer que reconozca los id en un echo que tengo de cada cronograma de un usuario*? Pulsa en [edit] aclarando tu problema y poniendo el código como texto. Si hay algún error, añade también el mensaje de error o explica el error o el resultado no deseado que estás obteniendo y lo que esperas obtener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos cosas:

1. Puedes simplificar esto, reflejando la estructura en un array. Cabe decir que faltan los valores por defecto, asumiré que cuando no se cumplen ninguna de las condiciones, se creará un `href` con valor `#` y con el texto `None`, esto lo puedes cambiar por lo que sea.
2. Cuando usas la etiqueta `<a>TEXTO</a>` debes poner algo en `TEXTO` o no se verá el enlace.

Apliquemos lo dicho:

```
$categories=array(
    0=>array('url'=>'#', 'txt'=>'None'),
    1=>array('url'=>'a_conograma_2023_i.php',   'txt'=>'Categoría 1'),
    2=>array('url'=>'a_conograma_2023_ii.php',  'txt'=>'Categoría 2'),
    3=>array('url'=>'a_conograma_2023_iii.php', 'txt'=>'Categoría 3'),
);

$index=$dario['categoria'] ?? 0;
$darioId= empty($dario['id']) ? '' : sprintf('?id=%s',$dario['id']);
$category=$categories[$index];
printf('<a href="%s%s">%s</a>',$category['url'],$darioId,$category['txt']);
```

Sin importar el valor, con este código, vas a tener el enlace.

Veamos dos casos de uso:

Con el valor:

```
$dario=array('categoria'=>1, 'id'=>50);
```

La salida será:

```
<a href="a_conograma_2023_i.php?id=50">Categoría 1</a>
```

Con el valor:

```
$dario=array('categoria'=>NULL);
```

La salida será:

```
<a href="#">None</a>
```

La ventaja de este código es su claridad y flexibilidad. Por ejemplo, si surge una categoría `4`, sólo la agregas a `$categories` y no tienes que cambiar nada más en el código. Si lo haces como en tu programa original, tendrás que agregar un nuevo `else` y cuando sean 50 categorías, tendrás un código kilométrico.

Otra ventaja es la portabilidad, o la posibilidad de reutilizar código. Si necesitaras esto en varias partes, pensemos en una clase que contenga `$categories` y desde esa clase, implementas la misma lógica en varios puntos del programa.

Comment: Muchas gracias excelente @A. Cedano